# Play MP3 in a loop with Mini MP3 Player

Tags: html, flash, mp3

I am using a [mini MP3 player](http://www.richnetapps.com/free-tools/mini-mp3-player/) to play an MP3 file. It is working fine, but I need to play the MP3 file in a loop. I have added a variable `loop` and set it to `true` but it still doesn't loop.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var so = new SWFObject("player.swf", "mp3player", "0", "0", "8", "#ffffff");
   so.addVariable("file", "1-05_Concert_ alla_rustica.mp3");
   so.addVariable("loop","true");
   so.write("flashcontent");
  </script>
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. Retagging.

Answer (score 3):

The MP3 player you are using doesn't seem to have a `loop` setting.

Here's a few players that do support looping:

- [EMFF](http://emff.sourceforge.net/) (Pretty sure "repeat playlist" applies to single files too)
- [jPlayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/) (by setting the `onSongComplete` event, search in the docs)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the mini mp3 player you chose does not support looping.

According to the publisher, it supports playFile(), pause(), rewind() and setSize().